# Is there a meaningful difference between Cat8x, Cat7x, and Cat6x rated RJ45 connectors?

Tags: cable

Most shielded higher-end RJ45 connectors for cat6 are still shielded and gold-plated, as are cat7 and cat8.

I've looked for any references; but every search I run is just about the cabling.

So, I'm wondering - I mean seriously, using a decent Cat6-rated RJ45 connector with a Cat8 ... I mean, honestly - is it really going to make a difference?

I'm suspicious of such labeling. I have a hard time believing that a couple centimeters of a Cat6-rated connector at the end of a cat8 cable is going to bring any throughput, bandwidth, frequency, or what have you - down to a generally cat6-level of performance.

But that's why I've been searching for this - maybe I can find some specs on a manufacturer's website ... hold on ... yeah, there really is nothing. The only thing I just found in reference to the RJ45 class of cat8 connectors is that the specifications called for backward compatibility. (https://www.flukenetworks.com/knowledge-base/applicationstandards-articles-copper/category-8-cabling-fact-sheet)
So, is this just a big nonsense marketing scheme?
I'm already like 99.999% sure a shielded cat6 spec RJ45 will do just as good of a job as a shielded cat8 spec RJ.

But, that's why I'm here - in case anybody knows for sure?

Comment: There is no Category-7. Category-6 is _unshielded_. Category-8 is new and shielded. ANSI/TIA/EIA specifies the cable categories, and all the current categories (3, 5e, 6, 6a, and 8) are unshielded, except Category-8. The ISO/IEC specify cable classes, and some are shielded, and Class-F is what most people call Category-7. Category-7 was never registered by ANSI/TIA/EIA. Yes, there is a real difference, and you must use the same category for all parts and pass the test suite post-installation to be certified for the category (very expensive tester), and the installer should provide the results.

Comment: @RonMaupin oh weird. I've just been pricing everything out. "Cat7" isn't a real standard then huh? I even saw a spool of cat7a.
I hate marketing with a passion. The listed cat7 shielded connectors are just as expensive and heavy-duty as most of the cat8's.
Man - now I'm even more confused

Comment: That's why they call it CAT7 rather than Category-7. It is probably the ISO/IEC Class-F, but you cannot really tell. ANSI/TIA/EIA specifies the cable categories, and has never had a Category-7. Some categories have come and gone, e.g. Category-5 was deregistered in the last century, but people still sell CAT5 cable.

Comment: The problem with Category-8 is that the length is so limited (30 meters in a channel, 24 meters for solid-core horizontal cable, and up to 6 meters of stranded patch cable) vs. the 100 meters for UTP categories. To get anything above Category-5e to pass the test suite, you really need a professional installer with the expensive tester, and it is really impossible to manually create a patch cable that passes the test suite, so ANSI/TIA/EIA has put that they must be factory made into the standard.

Comment: ah - ok. Gotcha. That helps quite a bit. So, basically - the only cabling most people would ever really need is cat6 right? Even with our business line; looking at the specs; cat8 would be a dreadful overkill for 200mbps dedicated line.g

Comment: Category-6 is really a step-child. It was an interim solution, that has only blossomed with the recent intermediate ethernet speeds. Category-5e can do 1 Gbps, and Category-6a was for 10 Gbps. The more recent 2.5 and 5 Gbps work on Category-6, but interfaces for those speeds are still fairly rare. That was really designed for the new Wi-Fi AP to switch connections for the higher speeds of things like AC Wave 2 and the new Wi-Fi 6 and above.